# Active directory migration with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I need to migrate from AD Windows2003Forest to AD 2016. I have below script to create users in bulk. My requirement is to map the same SID of older AD to new AD. For example in older AD SID='xyz' then it should be the same in newAD too as SID='xyz'

I am having all the users data along with SID in CSV format & am using below PowerShell script which is somehow not working. As of advice or suggestions.

powershell code snippent:

```
#Enter a path to your import CSV file
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\scripts\newusers.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{

       $Username    = $User.username
       $Password    = $User.password
       $Firstname   = $User.firstname
       $Lastname    = $User.lastname
       $Department = $User.department
       $OU           = $User.ou
       $sid     = $User.sid
    $UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
    $DistinguishedName = $User.DistinguishedName

       #Check if the user account already exists in AD
       if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
       {
               #If user does exist, output a warning message
               Write-Warning "A user account $Username has already exist in Active Directory."
       }
       else
       {
              #If a user does not exist then create a new user account

        #Account will be created in the OU listed in the $OU variable in the CSV file; don’t forget to change the domain name in the"-UserPrincipalName" variable
              New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
            -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
            -Department $Department `
        -DistinguishedName $DistinguishedName `
        -SID $sid `
            -Path $OU `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force)

       }
}
```

Comment: You can't assign a SID like that. Here's an [article about SIDs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers), but the important part is the RID master "FSMO" role (meaning the DC makes the SID). Added to this SID contain domain info, so if you have a new domain you can't have the same SID. Which is good, because you might want to use SID history during the migration in order to retain old permissions while you rebuild. I would also recommend that you use the Microsoft's AD Migration Tool rather than trying to manually script this.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to assign a SID as that's generated by the domain controller based on a RID.  If trying to *migrate* to a new forest then you'll need to perform a proper AD migration.  The old SIDs will be copied onto the migrated users' SID history attributes to allow permissions based on the old SID to still work.

If you simply want to upgrade to a newer version of AD then you're better off joining a newer domain controller to your existing Active Directory forest / domain.  The forest functional level mush be 2003 or higher.

As a side note, I'd recommend then getting rid of the 2003 servers as soon as possible as these are no longer supported by Microsoft.